# How to dynamically sort a set of weighted data in excel and display in a different set of cells?

Tags: excel

The following is the excel data I'm working with:

```
name    | poss  | curr  | diff  | weight
Adv TV  | 16.0  | 0     | -16.0 | 8
Tablets | 16.0  | 0     | -16.0 | 7
CRU GA  | 16.0  | 0     | -16.0 | 6
D. L.   | 5.0   | 0     | -5.0  | 5
Go Phone| 15.0  | 0     | -15.0 | 4
Close   | 16.0  | 0     | -16.0 | 3
Acc GP  | 16.0  | 0     | -16.0 | 2
Overtime| 0.00  | -2.00 | -2.0  | 1
```

`name`, `poss`(possible), and `curr`(current) are being pulled from other cells in the spreadsheet. `diff` is just `curr` minus `poss`. Weight is the relative weight given to each item.

What I'm wanting to do is this: first, sort by `diff` ascending. Then, sort by `weight` descending. So that, say, a row with a `diff` of -16 will ALWAYS be sorted above a row with a lower `diff` (I guess actually technically a higher diff) regardless of weight, and that the location of rows with the same `diff` value are determined by their weight. I want this to be done dynamically so that when one of the other cells that determine `name`, `poss`, or `curr` are changed, the sorting changes automatically. I then want to display all of this in a separate part of the spreadsheet, although I'm sure I can get that figured out with VLOOKUP and / or INDEX - the actual sorting of the data is what's driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

This [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro will resort the block of data originating from A1 and transfer the values to a new block starting at H3.

Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose View Code. When the VBE opens, paste this into the code sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:C")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(4), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Key2:=.Columns(5), Order2:=xlDescending, _
                        Key3:=.Columns(1), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            Range("H3").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Cells.Value2
        End With
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You were a little vague about the destination so I arbitrarily used H3. A named range may be better. It would certainly help in clearing any old entries and that is your next step. I was unable to suggest a method as to how to clear old entries since the specifics of that may change depending upon the exact location.